# Testcontainers ExecAsync fails to run /bin/ls

Tags: .net-core, testcontainers

I'm trying to exec something on an Oracle container created by Testcontainers.  If I run

> docker exec [pid] /bin/ls -ltr

Then the command works, but if I use the code below, it throws an exception

```
        _container = new OracleBuilder()
            .Build();
        var result = await _container.ExecAsync(new[] { "/bin/ls -ltr" });
        if (result.ExitCode != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(result.Stdout + result.Stderr);
        }
```

> OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/ls -ltr": stat /bin/ls -ltr: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: can you try "/bin/ls", "-ltr"